# Sitecore Scheduler not working

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

I have configured a scheduler which is working fine on my standalone environment.

But on the CM environment the scheduler last run time gets update but the Scheduler doesn't get executed.

Following are the configurations I am using.

[image]

[image]

The code I am using to call the execute the task :

```
namespace EloquaSitecoreConnector.Jobs
{
    public class PullEloquaData
    {
        public void EloquaContactExecution(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items, Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem command, Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem schedule)
        {
            try
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is database agent disabled on other servers (e.g. CD)?

Comment: We have some configuration related to Scheduler which tells to the sitecore which server(CM/Processing) will execute the Scheduler. You please check in both Servers CM and Process, it should be executed either one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to execute your scheduler with `PowerShell Script Options`? It provides you an option to execute the scheduler with a single click, the purpose to suggest this solution is when you click on the `Run Scheduler Task` option from the `Script Menu`, it will execute your scheduler without any delay. You can verify that scheduler executes or not. Find below image for more clarity:

[image]

For more details, you can refer: [Create and Configure Scheduler in Sitecore: Part-2](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/04/create-scheduler-is-sitecore-database.html)